# Analogue of differentiation for sequences?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I remember learning (2 semester calculus for engineers) about all the below ones, but nothing that fits in place of the question mark. Is there anything nontrivial?

```
(+)  ~  integration     ~   summation|series

(-)  ~  differentiation ~   ???
```

Comment: Look at finite calculus (for instance in Knuth, et al.s _Concrete Mathematics_), the analogue would be the finite difference $\Delta[f](x)$.

Comment: Just as a note, there are several types of finite differences.  GRY has given the most common one, the forward difference, but the backward and central differences are also used.  [See this response.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829487/differentiate-a-recurrence-relation/829515#829515)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analog is [finite difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference): $\Delta^{1}a_n = a_{n+1}-a_n$. As derivatives, they can be taken repeatedly: $\Delta^k a_n =  \Delta^{k-1} a_{n+1}-\Delta^{k-1} a_n$. They have some calculus-type properties, for example: if a sequence $a_n$ is given by a polynomial of degree $d$, then $\Delta^k a_n$ is given by a polynomial of degree $d-k$.  This is not hard to prove by induction. As a special case: $\Delta^d a$ is a constant sequence, and $\Delta^{d+1}a$ is identically zero: just as with derivatives of  polynomials.

The converse is also true: if some $\Delta^k$ is identically zero, then the sequence is given by a polynomial of degree $\le k-1$. One can even recover the coefficients of this polynomial from the sequence. This is a special case of "[Umbral Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus#Umbral_Taylor_series)" (I admit never seeing the term "umbral" anywhere other than in this Wikipedia article.)